# Performing advanced queries similar to ElasticSearch in React Native while offline

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, react-native

I am creating a mobile app in React Native that needs to cache tens of thousands of records. While online, the app makes API calls to a back-end that is powered by ElasticSearch. If the app is offline, I need a solution that can do the same advanced queries, such as weighted searching, fuzzy searching, custom analyzers, and aggregated metadata.

Are there any React Native or JavaScript libraries out there that can help me perform these advanced queries when offline?

Here are some solutions I am looking into, but all of them seem to be pretty underpowered in comparison to ElasticSearch:

- ElasticLunr.js
- Lunr.js
- react-native-sqlite-storage
- PouchDB
- Realm